# Linq to entity select and count?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a table like you can see below

Table items

```
ID          Type               Sold (bit)
--------------------------------------------
1           Book                 1
2           Phone                0
3           TV                   1
4           TV                   1
5           TV                   1
6           TV                   0
7           Phone                1
8           Phone                0
```

I need to group by type, count it and count how many items are sold.
So I can get the result like you can see below

```
Phone 3; Sold 1
TV    4; Sold 3
Book  1; Sold 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = from row in table
            group row.Sold by row.Type into g
            select new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Sold = g.Count(s => s) };
```

Comment: @Andrew: In that case, see the updated answer.  If it is a bit type, it should map to a `bool` so we'd just want to count the number of `true` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = 
 from p in products 
 group p by p.Type into g 
 select new {TypeDesc = g.Key, NumberOfIDs = g.Count(p => p.ID), UnitsSold = g.Sum(p => p.Sold)};
```